# how to enlarge scatter plot

Tags: r, graph, scatter-plot

[image]

I cant fingure out how to enlarge it
For example, on a scale 0 to 40 on y-axis  and -5 to 5 on x-axis , so I can see better

Comment: `plot(..., xlim=c(-5,5), ylim=c(0,40))`

Answer (score 0):

```
ggplot(data=NULL, aes(return_1, reg1$fitted_values)) + 
  xlim(-5,5) +
  ylim(0,40)
```